Unpivot with Pandas - Excel a specific type of matrix?
I am using Python/Pandas to extract data from an excel file and do some processes but I am stuck dealing with this:
I have this data (is not formatted as a table) in my data frame:



column1
column2
column3
column4
column5
column6
column7





Tesla Cars


Toyota Cars





SUV
SEDAN
TRUCK
SUV
SEDAN
TRUCK


Dealer NYC
10
20
5
15
25
10


Dealer Texas
20
30
10
25
35
15



And I would it to look this:



column1
column2
coulmn3
column4
column5






SUV
SEDAN
TRUCK


Dealer NYC
Tesla Cars
10
20
5


Dealer NYC
Toyota Cars
15
25
10


Dealer Texas
Tesla Cars
20
30
10


Dealer Texas
Toyota Cars
25
35
15



I tried to get it to work since Wednesday until Friday but I just could not figure out the logic for it.
It can be that I also have several car brands and all of them would be above the string "SUV" and the car types will always be SUV, SEDAN,TRUCK and the corresponding values under them.
I tried to go about by creating a nested dictionary, where I would save the string right above SUV as the "key" then SUV,SEDAN,TRUCK as the nested keys, and their values as the numbers that are under each of them respectively, it should have looked something like this:
brand_1 : { Tesla cars: {SUV: [10,20], SEDAN:[20,30], TRUCK:[5,10]}
brand_2: { Toyota_cars: {SUV:[15,25], SEDAN:[25,35], TRUCK:[10,15]}
Then unpack the main key(Tesla Cars, Toyota Cars) in a new column and the values of the nested keys( [10,20],[20,30], [5,10], [15,25],[25,35], [10,15] in their respective columns. But of course it did not work.
I am sure I am overcomplicating things and that there is a much easier method and logic to achieve this, can you please guide me to the correct way to deal with such data?
I tried creating a nested dictionary with the car brand as the main key and the different type of cars as their nested keys with their values and then unpack but it did not work. My logic cannot create the correct dictionary, I guess I am not relating the keys and values correctly.
EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of what my script outputs when I write the df to excel (left) and the right is what I would like to the df to look like:
enter image description here

Here's one approach:

Read the file with pd.read_excel, specifying header and index_col.
Use df.stack to move column level 0 to the index. With pd version >= 2.1.0, pass future_stack=True to avoid a FutureWarning.

import pandas as pd

file_name = 'myfile.xlsx'

df = (pd.read_excel(file_name, 
                    header=[0,1], 
                    index_col=[0])
      .stack(level=0)
      )

# pd >= 2.1.0: `df.stack(level=0, future_stack=True)

Output:
                          SUV  SEDAN  TRUCK
Dealer NYC   Tesla Cars    10     20      5
             Toyota Cars   15     25     10
Dealer Texas Tesla Cars    20     30     10
             Toyota Cars   25     35     15

If you want to write this back to Excel, you can use pd.to_excel, adding merge_cells=False if you want to avoid getting merged cells (in this case: for index level 0):
pd.to_excel(file_name, merge_cells=False)

Output:


Thank you so much for your replay @ouroboros1.
My original file had a lot of stuff and data that I had been editing with my script so my df at this point has been going through other processing steps to get to where I showed above. Can you instead show me the steps where you already have pandas dataframe "df"?

That would be just df.stack(level=0). But if that's not working, your df (i.e., the first table in your question) probably has an unexpected formatting (without a proper MultiIndex for the columns). If so, please update your question with the proper pandas form of your df. I mean: provide the first table again (the very same!), but as constructed in python. You can use df.to_dict() and assign it to a variable, e.g., data and then add df = pd.DataFrame(data).

Thank you again for your reply! I added a screenshot of my excel output when I do df to excel (left) and the right is what I am looking for.

Thanks, but please don't add pictures of the result of df.to_excel. Instead, post the result of df.to_dict() at that point in your script. Otherwise, what you are asking is to write something to Excel in your code, then to retrieve that again from Excel, change it, and write it to Excel again. That makes little sense.
